# getting the difference between two rows and perform mathematical operation on the difference mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My data set for example looks like this

```
ID|Value
 1|10
 1|3
 2|9
 2|10
 2|15
```

I need to find the difference between two consecutive elements of the same ID and store the value and then again find the difference and multiply the stored value with the new difference all of values with the same ID. This must go on till there are elements with the same ID.
Hence my final data set should looklike

```
ID|Value
 1|-7
 2|5
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how i should go about this using sql

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Hence, there is no such thing as "two consecutive [rows]", unless you have a column specifying the ordering.  I don't see such a column.

Comment: Where does `-5` for id 2 come from?

Comment: @Barmar sorry its 5

Comment: If you have another column you haven't shown that specifies the ordering, you can do what you want using a user-defined variable to hold the value from the previous row, and then subtract the current row's value from it.

Comment: Where does that come from? Is it `(9-10) * (10-15)`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff what I meant was rows with the same ID bellow each other

Comment: He's telling you that 'below' doesn't mean anything unless you have a column you can order by.

Comment: @Barmar (10-9)*(15-10)=1*5=5

Comment: @HartCO i have a column that has dates, I could use that. New to this so i did not know if i had to include that also sorry.

Comment: @AbuKurian Why is it `10-9` and not `9-10`? For ID 1 it's `10-3`.

Comment: Yeah, including that would be helpful, so it's not arbitrary ordering.

Comment: @Barmar thats supposed to be 3-10. My mistake.

Comment: @HartCO so how do you suggest i go about it?

Comment: So it should be `-7` instead of `10`? Please update the question to show what you really want. And show your attempt to solve it, since SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @AbuKurian I told you above how to go about it. Use a user-defined variable to hold the value from the previous row.

Comment: `SELECT (Value - @prev_value) as diff, @prev_value := Value FROM ...`

Comment: The problem is i dont know how to approach this. So i could not try anything  out. Would really help me if you showed me how to.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the differences between consecutive rows -

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT T.*,
    -> IF(T.TID <> @P ,@RN:=1,@RN:=@RN+1) RN,
    -> IF(T.TID <> @P ,0, @PVAL) PVAL,
    -> IF(T.TID <> @P ,0, T.VALUE * 1.00 - @PVAL) DIFF,
    -> @P:=T.TID,
    -> @PVAL:=T.VALUE
    -> FROM(SELECT @RN:=0,@P:=0,@PVAL:=0.00,@DIFF:=0.00) RN,T
    -> ORDER BY T.TID,T.dt;
+------------+------+-------+------+------+------+-----------+----------------+
| dt         | TID  | Value | RN   | PVAL | DIFF | @P:=T.TID | @PVAL:=T.VALUE |
+------------+------+-------+------+------+------+-----------+----------------+
| 2017-01-01 |    1 |    10 |    1 | 0    |    0 |         1 |             10 |
| 2017-01-02 |    1 |     3 |    2 | 10   |   -7 |         1 |              3 |
| 2017-01-01 |    2 |     9 |    1 | 0    |    0 |         2 |              9 |
| 2017-01-02 |    2 |    10 |    2 | 9    |    1 |         2 |             10 |
| 2017-01-03 |    2 |    15 |    3 | 10   |    5 |         2 |             15 |
+------------+------+-------+------+------+------+-----------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

BUT there is no aggregation function in sql (any version as far as I know) that will calculate the product (if that's the right word) of the differences. What's more you seem to want to discard the first row for every tid. 
You could do this by group_concatenating the differences into a table and then calling a stored procedure which initiates a call to dynamic sql (you cannot use dynamic sql in stored functions by the way).

This stored procedure

```
drop procedure if exists f;
delimiter //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` procedure `F`(
    instring varchar(200)
)

LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
begin
declare   tempstring varchar(100);
declare   outstring  varchar(100);
declare  tempid int;
declare  checkit int;
declare maxrecs int;
set checkit = 0;
set maxrecs = (select count(*) from temp);

looper: while   checkit < maxrecs do
select tid,calc into    tempid,tempstring from temp limit checkit,1; 
set checkit = checkit + 1;  
if instr(tempstring,',')  = 0 then 
    update temp
    set    rsult  = tempstring; 
else
    set outstring  = replace(tempstring,',','*');
    set outstring  = concat('update temp set rsult = (Select ',outstring,') where tid = ', tempid, ';');
    set @sqlstmt = outstring;
    #select checkit, maxrecs, outstring;
    prepare sqlstmt from @sqlstmt;  
    execute sqlstmt;
    deallocate prepare sqlstmt;
end if;

end while;
end //

delimiter ;
```

when called in this script produces your desired outcome

```
*ariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists temp;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table temp as
    -> select s.tid,group_concat(s.diff) calc, 1.00 as rsult
    -> from
    -> (
    -> SELECT T.*,
    -> IF(T.TID <> @P ,@RN:=1,@RN:=@RN+1) RN,
    -> IF(T.TID <> @P ,0, @PVAL) PVAL,
    -> IF(T.TID <> @P ,0, T.VALUE * 1.00 - @PVAL) DIFF,
    -> @P:=T.TID,
    -> @PVAL:=T.VALUE
    -> FROM(SELECT @RN:=0,@P:=0,@PVAL:=0.00,@DIFF:=0.00) RN,T
    -> ORDER BY T.TID,T.dt
    -> ) s
    -> where s.rn <> 1
    -> group by s.tid;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.23 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> call f('1');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from temp;
+------+-----------+-------+
| tid  | calc      | rsult |
+------+-----------+-------+
|    1 | -7.00     | -7.00 |
|    2 | 1.00,5.00 |  5.00 |
+------+-----------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)*
```